# How to plot heatmap based on GradientBoost results?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, seaborn

I want to print a heatmap of a confusion matrix based on my results of y_predict and y_train.

I'm a bit stuck and I already looked up the pandas documentation of the heatmap, but still don't know how to apply it on my results. The dataset I used is about incomes and has categorical and numerical data. I've already applied the GB classifier and I got an result.
The only thing that remains is the heatmap.

```
print(confusion_matrix(y_train,y_pred_train))
print(y_train)
```

this was the outcome

```
Confusion Matrix:


[[14151   710]
 [ 1844  2831]]
Name: income, Length: 19536, dtype: int64
```

this was an attempt to make a heatmap

```
import seaborn as sns
class_names = y_train, y_pred_train

def print_confusion_matrix(confusion_matrix, class_names, figsize = (10,7), fontsize=14):
    df_cm = pd.DataFrame(
        confusion_matrix, index=class_names, columns=class_names, 
    )
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    try:
        heatmap = sns.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, fmt="d")
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Confusion matrix values must be integers.")
    heatmap.yaxis.set_ticklabels(heatmap.yaxis.get_ticklabels(), rotation=0, ha='right', fontsize=fontsize)
    heatmap.xaxis.set_ticklabels(heatmap.xaxis.get_ticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right', fontsize=fontsize)
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
    return fig
```

which returned

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-3bd0e9ee90a4> in <module>()
     18     plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
     19     return fig
---> 20 print(fig)

NameError: name 'fig' is not defined
```

So what am I missing when I'm making the heatmap of the confusion matrix on my results?

Comment: You can call the function with your confusion matrix, see my answer for an example

Comment: And the error on `print(fig)` is that `fig` is defined inside the function, and if you want to use it outside the scope of the function, you can set it with `fig = print_confusion_matrix(...` since it's returned from your function with `return fig`

Answer (score 0):

You can call your `print_confusion_matrix` function with the confusion matrix and class names list as parameters:

```
def print_confusion_matrix(confusion_matrix, class_names, figsize = (10,7), fontsize=14):
    df_cm = pd.DataFrame(
        confusion_matrix, index=class_names, columns=class_names, 
    )
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    try:
        heatmap = sns.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, fmt="d")
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Confusion matrix values must be integers.")
    heatmap.yaxis.set_ticklabels(heatmap.yaxis.get_ticklabels(), rotation=0, ha='right', fontsize=fontsize)
    heatmap.xaxis.set_ticklabels(heatmap.xaxis.get_ticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right', fontsize=fontsize)
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
    return fig

confusion_matrix = np.array([[14151, 710], [1844, 2831]])
fig = print_confusion_matrix(confusion_matrix, ['0', '1'])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!